# Python selectors library - how to send two ways on the same socket?

Tags: python, sockets

I'm attempting to use the Python `selectors` library ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/selectors.html)) to send messages two ways.  I used this resource to get a basic understanding of the `selectors` library:

https://realpython.com/python-sockets/

This is the GitHub with the code for it:

https://github.com/realpython/materials/tree/master/python-sockets-tutorial

Before somebody marks this as a duplicate, which it is not, I'm asking specifically about 2-way socket communication using the `selectors` library, which is more modern and different that the `select` library, which the other answers out there are for.

In case the above link breaks and to follow the SO policy of not providing only a link, here are the multiconnection server and client, with some minor rearranging and added comments by me (all credit to original author(s) via above links):

MulticonnServer.py:

```
# MulticonnServer.py

import sys
import socket
import selectors
import types


def main():
    # instantiate a selector
    sel = selectors.DefaultSelector()

    # define host, port, and number of connections
    host = '127.0.0.1'
    port = 65432
    num_conns = 2

    # instantiate a socket
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    # bind and listen
    sock.bind((host, port))
    sock.listen()
    print('listening on', (host, port))
    # set non-blocking
    sock.setblocking(False)
    # register the socket with the selector
    sel.register(sock, selectors.EVENT_READ, data=None)

    try:
        # while True:
        # ToDo: figure out why have to multiply x2 here ??
        for i in range(num_conns * 2):
            # execution waits here until ??
            events = sel.select(timeout=None)
            for key, mask in events:
                if key.data is None:
                    accept_wrapper(sel, key.fileobj)
                else:
                    service_connection(sel, key, mask)
                # end if
            # end for
        # end for
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('caught keyboard interrupt, exiting')
    finally:
        sel.close()
    # end try
# end function

def accept_wrapper(sel, sock):
    conn, addr = sock.accept()  # Should be ready to read

    print('accepted connection from', addr)
    conn.setblocking(False)
    data = types.SimpleNamespace(addr=addr, inb=b"", outb=b"")
    events = selectors.EVENT_READ | selectors.EVENT_WRITE
    sel.register(conn, events, data=data)
# end function

def service_connection(sel, key, mask):
    sock = key.fileobj
    data = key.data
    if mask & selectors.EVENT_READ:
        recv_data = sock.recv(1024)  # Should be ready to read
        if recv_data:
            data.outb += recv_data
        else:
            print("closing connection to", data.addr)
            sel.unregister(sock)
            sock.close()
    if mask & selectors.EVENT_WRITE:
        if data.outb:
            print("echoing", repr(data.outb), "to", data.addr)
            sent = sock.send(data.outb)  # Should be ready to write
            data.outb = data.outb[sent:]
        # end if
    # end if
# end function

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

MulticonnClient.py:

```
# MulticonnClient.py

import sys
import socket
import selectors
import types


def main():
    sel = selectors.DefaultSelector()
    messages = [b"Message 1 from client.", b"Message 2 from client."]

    host = '127.0.0.1'
    port = 65432
    num_conns = 2

    start_connections(sel, host, int(port), int(num_conns), messages)

    try:
        while True:
            events = sel.select(timeout=1)
            if events:
                for key, mask in events:
                    service_connection(key, mask, sel)
            # Check for a socket being monitored to continue.
            if not sel.get_map():
                break
            # end if
        # end while
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('caught keyboard interrupt, exiting')
    finally:
        sel.close()
    # end try
# end function

def start_connections(sel, host, port, num_conns, messages):
    server_addr = (host, port)
    for i in range(0, num_conns):
        connid = i + 1
        print("starting connection", connid, "to", server_addr)
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        sock.setblocking(False)
        sock.connect_ex(server_addr)
        events = selectors.EVENT_READ | selectors.EVENT_WRITE
        data = types.SimpleNamespace(
            connid=connid,
            msg_total=sum(len(m) for m in messages),
            recv_total=0,
            messages=list(messages),
            outb=b"",
        )
        sel.register(sock, events, data=data)
    # end for
# end function

def service_connection(key, mask, sel):
    sock = key.fileobj
    data = key.data
    if mask & selectors.EVENT_READ:
        recv_data = sock.recv(1024)  # Should be ready to read
        if recv_data:
            print("received", repr(recv_data), "from connection", data.connid)
            data.recv_total += len(recv_data)
        if not recv_data or data.recv_total == data.msg_total:
            print("closing connection", data.connid)
            sel.unregister(sock)
            sock.close()
    if mask & selectors.EVENT_WRITE:
        if not data.outb and data.messages:
            data.outb = data.messages.pop(0)
        if data.outb:
            print("sending", repr(data.outb), "to connection", data.connid)
            sent = sock.send(data.outb)  # Should be ready to write
            data.outb = data.outb[sent:]
        # end if
    # end if
# end function

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

These programs work great, but what I'd like to do next is send one message one way (ex. client to server as the above already does) and the next message the other way (ex. server to client) on the same socket.

I'm not 100% sure this is even possible.  Especially the line:

```
sel.register(sock, selectors.EVENT_READ, data=None)
```

in the server is concerning.  How can this example be re-worked to provide 2-way communication on the same socket?

--- Edit ---

I found changing the `sel.register` line in `MulticonnServer.py` to:

```
sel.register(sock, selectors.EVENT_READ | selectors.EVENT_WRITE, data=None)
```

Does not cause a crash so maybe there is hope?  I'm still not sure how to set up 2-way comm on the same socket however.

Answer (score 1):

I was working on this as well and got it to work. What I had to do was:

- create a list to capture any pending_messages
- and, modify service_connection() as follows

It is actually not necessary to set `selectors.EVENT_WRITE`. It does not seem to matter.

The first part is:

```
#
# capture pending messages: (fd,message) where fd is the socket fd, a numeric integer value. For example:

pending_messages = []

...
pending_messages.append( (key.fd, message) )
...
```

And then inside service_connection (see bottom part which is the only mod):

```
def service_connection(sel, key, mask):
    sock = key.fileobj
    data = key.data
    if mask & selectors.EVENT_READ:
        recv_data = sock.recv(1024)  # Should be ready to read
        if recv_data:
            data.outb += recv_data
        else:
            print("closing connection to", data.addr)
            sel.unregister(sock)
            sock.close()
    if mask & selectors.EVENT_WRITE:
        if data.outb:
            print("echoing", repr(data.outb), "to", data.addr)
            sent = sock.send(data.outb)  # Should be ready to write
            data.outb = data.outb[sent:]
        elif len(pending_messages) > 0:
            if pending_messages[0][0] == key.fd:
                data.outb = pending_messages[0][1]
                pending_messages.pop(0)
# end function
```

It does seems to matter that the system is ready to write. You can't just send messages anytime or anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your edition is the answer. If you observe in the [selectors.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/selectors.py) source code the second parameter in the register is a [list of events](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/696d2324cf2a54e20e8d6a6739fa97ba815a8be9/Lib/selectors.py#L101).

```
@abstractmethod
    def register(self, fileobj, events, data=None):
        """Register a file object.
        Parameters:
        fileobj -- file object or file descriptor
        events  -- events to monitor (bitwise mask of EVENT_READ|EVENT_WRITE)
        data    -- attached data
        Returns:
        SelectorKey instance
        Raises:
        ValueError if events is invalid
        KeyError if fileobj is already registered
        OSError if fileobj is closed or otherwise is unacceptable to
                the underlying system call (if a system call is made)
        Note:
        OSError may or may not be raised
        """
        raise NotImplementedError
```

Also, you can find the same details in the [documentation that you provide.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/selectors.html#selectors.SelectorKey)

---- Edition -----

If you want to see more details add some print to for in events in the server and client.

**Server:**

```
for key, mask in events:
    print("key val {}".format(key))
    if key.data is None:
        accept_wrapper(key.fileobj)
    else:
        service_connection(key, mask)
```

**Client:**

```
if events:
    for key, mask in events:
        print("key val {}".format(key.fileobj))
        service_connection(key, mask)
```

In both console you can observe the remote address (raddr) and local address (laddr) used, the ports in the console indicates us that every socket is sending data in bidirectional way.

**Example print in server:**

```
SelectorKey(fileobj=<socket.socket fd=5, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, laddr=('127.0.0.1', 33123), raddr=('127.0.0.1', 64401)>, fd=5, events=3, data=namespace(addr=('127.0.0.1', 64401), inb=b'', outb=b''))
```

**Example print in client:**

```
<socket.socket fd=4, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, laddr=('127.0.0.1', 64401), raddr=('127.0.0.1', 33123)>
```

Finally, as the [linux socket](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/socket.2.html) documentation describes, the **`SOCK_STREAM`** type provides a two-way, connection-based byte streams.

I hope this edition makes this answer clear to you.

Comment: So how could I edit the above to send one message each way?  The documentation does not make this clear.